# Spark with Hive warehouse connector within oozie

Tags: apache-spark, hive, oozie

I'm using spark with hive warehouse connector. When i start a spark-submit from the edge node using a shell script it works perfectly, but when i start an oozie job that runs the same script it generate an error.

Here is my shell script :

```
echo "running Spark batch"
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name $NAME \
--queue $QUEUE \
--driver-memory 12g \
--jars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.7.1.5.0-257.jar\
--conf spark.security.credentials.hiveserver2.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url="jdbc:hive2://$host:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true" \
--conf spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url.principal="$principal" \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=com.qubole.spark.hiveacid.HiveAcidAutoConvertExtension" \
--conf spark.kryo.registrator="com.qubole.spark.hiveacid.util.HiveAcidKyroRegistrator" \
--class $MAIN_CLASS \
$JAR_PATH
```

Here is also my workflow oozie:

```
<workflow-app name="workflow_scc" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3">
<start to="shell-scc-rco"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="shell-scc-rco">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
                <value>myqueue</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>run_batch.sh</exec>
        <file>${batch}#run_batch.sh</file>
        <file>${keytab}#application.keytab</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="shell-scc-rtc"/>
    <error to="email-ko"/>
</action>
<end name="End"/>
```

When i start my oozie job, i'm getting this error :

```
    Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myhost:11002/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true;auth=delegationToken: HTTP Response code: 401)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.executeSimpleJdbc(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:326)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.sql(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:130)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.getDataQuarterHive(DataProcessorRco.scala:133)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.processQuarterHiveOrFiles(DataProcessorRco.scala:105)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.ComputeIndicators(DataProcessorRco.scala:55)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.run(DataProcessorRco.scala:41)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.main(DataProcessorRco.scala:34)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco.main(DataProcessorRco.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:665)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myhost:11002/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true;auth=delegationToken: HTTP Response code: 401)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2385)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2110)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1622)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:554)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(HS2JDBCWrapper.scala:450)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(HS2JDBCWrapper.scala:458)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.DefaultJDBCWrapper.getConnector(HS2JDBCWrapper.scala)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.lambda$new$0(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:94)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.executeSimpleJdbc(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:322)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myhost:11002/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true;auth=delegationToken: HTTP Response code: 401
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:349)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:291)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2395)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2381)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myhost:11002/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true;auth=delegationToken: HTTP Response code: 401
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:906)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:321)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: HTTP Response code: 401
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flushUsingHttpClient(THttpClient.java:262)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flush(THttpClient.java:313)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:73)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.send_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:170)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:162)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:887)
        ... 26 more

         ApplicationMaster host: myhost
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: 44387
         start time: 1625665219416
         final status: FAILED
         tracking URL: https://myhost:8090/proxy/application_1622214113087_300744/
         user: e8b-b85cf6d7591c-d_bib180536
21/07/07 15:40:47 ERROR yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myhost:11002/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true;auth=delegationToken: HTTP Response code: 401)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.executeSimpleJdbc(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:326)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.sql(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:130)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.getDataQuarterHive(DataProcessorRco.scala:133)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.processQuarterHiveOrFiles(DataProcessorRco.scala:105)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.ComputeIndicators(DataProcessorRco.scala:55)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.run(DataProcessorRco.scala:41)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco$.main(DataProcessorRco.scala:34)
        at my.class.DataProcessorRco.main(DataProcessorRco.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:665)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myhost:11002/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true;auth=delegationToken: HTTP Response code: 401)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2385)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2110)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1622)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:554)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(HS2JDBCWrapper.scala:450)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(HS2JDBCWrapper.scala:458)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.DefaultJDBCWrapper.getConnector(HS2JDBCWrapper.scala)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.lambda$new$0(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:94)
        at com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.executeSimpleJdbc(HiveWarehouseSessionImpl.java:322)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myhost:11002/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true;auth=delegationToken: HTTP Response code: 401
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:349)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:291)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2395)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2381)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myhost:11002/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice;ssl=true;auth=delegationToken: HTTP Response code: 401
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:906)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:321)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: HTTP Response code: 401
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flushUsingHttpClient(THttpClient.java:262)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flush(THttpClient.java:313)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:73)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.send_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:170)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:162)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:887)
        ... 26 more

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1622214113087_300744 finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1194)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1585)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:847)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:922)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:931)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Do you have any idea how i can fix this ?

Thanks,